# Design flaw in Wi-Fi EasyMesh or a poor implementation?

Tags: wifi

Extending a wireless network with [Wi-Fi EasyMesh](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-easymesh) is easy, but that may come at a cost of security. I was surprised that setting up the Mesh network with [Zyxel MPro Mesh](https://service-provider.zyxel.com/global/en/mpro-mesh-solutions) devices (e.g. DX3301-T0 router & WX3100-T0 extender) required zero configuration: the extender was connected with a wire for a moment and that was it. On the next boot the Mesh worked, and the extender was configured with the SSIDs and passwords from the router.

However, if the router is willingly giving the passwords to the extender it would also give them to any client asking for them. This means that anyone having access to the wired network will get access to the wireless network, too. Is the EasyMesh designed to work this way, or is it just the Zyxel MPro Mesh implementation? (Getting the [Wi-Fi EasyMesh Specification](https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wi-fi-easymesh-specification) or [Technology Overview](https://www.wi-fi.org/file/wi-fi-certified-easymesh-technology-overview-2022) from the Wi-Fi Alliance requires giving your PII to them.)

I would expect that the discovery protocol should only be enabled temporarily when setting up a new extender & the Mesh itself should use another protocol independent from the discovery protocol. Unfortunately, the Zyxel router only has a single on/off option for the MPro Mesh.